# How can I get rid of this self-calling function?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I found this awesome snippet on the internet:

```
function f(a,b,c,d){for(d?d=b.toUpperCase():b=4;!d&&b--;d=(d=d.replace(/-(.)/g,f))in(new Image).style&&d)d=[['Moz-','Webkit-','Ms-','O-'][b]]+a;return d}
```

It takes the name of a css property, and adds the correct vendor prefix automatically.

I golfed it a bit to make it smaller:

```
function f(a,b,c){for(c?c=b.toUpperCase():b=4;!c&&b--;c=(c=c.replace(/-(.)/,f))in(new Image).style&&c)c=["Moz-","Webkit-","Ms-","O-"][b]+a;return c}
```

I would like to submit it to 140bytes, but this function calls itself, which means that it pollutes the global namespace with a variable (f)

How can I change it so it doesn't call itself?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vCkew/

Comment: Your function doesn't seem to work properly, as it results in CSS property names without any dashes in them. (It's supposed to be "-moz-transition", not "MozTransition".)

Comment: @Pointy: When using them in JavaScript `mozTransition` etc. are correct.

Comment: Ah OK - I thought the point was to  "fix" CSS.  OK then :-)

Comment: Why do you not want this function to be recursive?

Answer (score 0):

Use some scoping:

```
var myFunction = function(a, b, c) {
    var f = function(a, b, c) {
        for (c ? c = b.toUpperCase() : b = 4; !c && b--; c = (c = c.replace(/-(.)/, f)) in (new Image).style && c)
        c = ["Moz-", "Webkit-", "Ms-", "O-"][b] + a;
        return c;
    }
    return f(a, b, c);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/vCkew/3/

Comment: The problem is that "f" is still there as the callback to the `.replace()` call.  You could change that to "myFunction", but we're back to a global variable ...

Comment: @Pointy hmmm did not notice that. One sec

Comment: It does work, but I could of done that pretty easily. I'm looking for a rewrite of the function so it doesn't call itself.

Comment: @williammalo but u ddnt :-P I did

Comment: @williammalo The whole idea of that function is that it is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `arguments` keyword to get the function:

```
function(a,b,c){for(c?c=b.toUpperCase():b=4;!c&&b--;c=(c=c.replace(/-(.)/,arguments.callee))in(new Image).style&&c)c=["Moz-","Webkit-","Ms-","O-"][b]+a;return c}
```

To make it work in your jsfiddle:

```
document.write((function(a,b,c){for(c?c=b.toUpperCase():b=4;!c&&b--;c=(c=c.replace(/-(.)/,arguments.callee))in(new Image).style&&c)c=["Moz-","Webkit-","Ms-","O-"][b]+a;return c})('transition'));​
```

NOTE: This does actually answer your question to make the function not call itself but it does remove the function from the global namespace.

Comment: It's closer to what I'm looking for, but the function is still recursive, it just does so annonimously. Also, argument.callee is deprecated, and should not be used.